# MCP1702 5v: Can work with 6V input and get 5V

Tags: voltage-regulator, datasheet

I'm reading the datasheet of the MCP1702.
At page 4 (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22008E.pdf) it says

`input voltage VIN = VOUT(MAX) + VDROPOUT(MAX) or VIN = 2.7V (whichever is greater)`

If I did understand correctly, the VDROPOUT is max 650mV at same page for the 5V out.

So, can it works at 5V/250mA with 5.650 V of Vin?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as your input voltage is greater than your output voltage plus the dropout voltage, the regulator should be able to maintain the fixed output voltage. Don't forget the input and output capacitors though, they can help keep the output stable and also provide you with a little bit of a backup in case there are any fluctuations in your supply.